# ngFor length in Angular 5

Tags: angular, count, angular5, ngfor

I have three buttons :

All (Reals+ Fakes), Reals(total count), Fakes(total count)

I am trying to get the total count of my total feeds which will be shown in All.

And the total count of feed.feed_type != '' which will be shown Reals.

And the total count of feed.feed_type == '' which will be shown Fakes.

**Feeds Model**

```js
export class Feeds {
  feed_id: string;
  feed_category: string;
  feed_title: any;
  feed_description: string;
  feed_terms: string;
  feed_type: string;
  checked: false;
  }
```

**Feeds Component:**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { MyService } from '../shared/services/my-service.service';
import { FeedsService } from '../shared/services/feeds.service';
import { Feeds } from '../shared/services/feeds';
import { Feed } from '../shared/services/feed';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-feeds',
  templateUrl: './feeds.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./feeds.component.scss']
})

export class FeedsComponent implements OnInit {

  feeds: Observable<Feed[]>;
  Reals: boolean;
  Fakes: boolean;
  selectedFeedType = '';


  constructor(private myService: MyService, private feedsService: FeedsService) {
    this.selectedFeedType = 'All';
    this.Reals = true;
    this.Fakes = true;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.feeds = this.myService.feeds;
    this.myService.loadAll();
  }


  SelectedFeedsType(event: any) {
    this.selectedFeedType = event.target.value;
    if (this.selectedFeedType === 'All') {
      this.Reals = true;
      this.Fakes = true;
    } else if (this.selectedFeedType === 'Reals') {
      this.Reals = true;
      this.Fakes = false;
    } else if (this.selectedFeedType === 'Fakes') {
      this.Reals = false;
      this.Fakes = true;
    }
  }

}
```

**MyService:**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FeedsService } from './feeds.service';
import { Feed } from './Feed';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  feeds: Observable<Feed[]>;
  private _feeds: BehaviorSubject<Feed[]>;
  private baseUrl: string;
  total = '';
  private dataStore: {
    feeds: any
  };

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
      this.baseUrl  = environment.API_ENDPOINT + 'feeds';
      this.dataStore = { feeds: [] };
      this._feeds = <BehaviorSubject<Feed[]>>new BehaviorSubject([]);
      this.feeds = this._feeds.asObservable();
    }

   

     loadAll() { 
        this.http.get(this.baseUrl).subscribe(feeds => { 
        this.dataStore.feeds = feeds;
        console.log(feeds.length);
        const Reals = feeds.filter(feed => feed.feed_type !== '').length; 
        console.log(Reals);
        const Fakes = feeds.length - Reals;
        console.log(Fakes);
        this._feeds.next(Object.assign({}, this.dataStore).feeds);},
        error => console.log('Could not load feeds.'));
      }

    change(feeds) {
      this._feeds.next(feeds);
    }

}
```

**Feeds.Component.html**

```html
<ul>
  <li><input  type="radio"  name="feedType" value="All" checked (change)="SelectedFeedsType($event)">All</li>
  <li><input  type="radio"  name="feedType" value="Reals"  (change)="SelectedFeedsType($event)">Reals</li>
  <li><input  type="radio"  name="feedType" value="Fakes"  (change)="SelectedFeedsType($event)">Fakes</li>
</ul>

<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr><th>Feeds</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>
        <div class="storetabContent"  *ngFor="let feed of feeds | async">
        <ng-container *ngIf="Reals && feed.feed_type != ''">
          <p>{{ feed.feed_title }}</p>
          <p>{{ feed.feed_category }}</p>
          <b>REAL</b>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngIf="Fakes && feed.feed_type == ''">
            <p>{{ feed.feed_title }}</p>
            <p>{{ feed.feed_category }}</p>
            <b>FAKE</b>
        </ng-container>
        </div>
      </td></tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Any suggestions, help appreciated.

Comment: This question can't be answered without your component code. See [mcve] and also [ask] a good question.

Comment: That said: **If** I had to guess as to a solution direction it probably involves subscribing to the observable in the component and calculating the totals there and saving them as local variables. But without your component code and the data structure you are using it is anyone's guess.

Comment: I wouldn't really recommend having two ng-containers. They are displaying the same exact info, title, category, and name. Follow DRY principles. Instead, consider filtering your data elsewhere. Then, keeping count will be much easier for you. Otherwise, you could try doing it when you initially get the data and count it that way.

Comment: @Igor
I have updated my question with both component and service code.

Comment: Could you also include the structure for `Feed`. Either the interface structure and/or the json would be sufficient.

Comment: @Igor, Added the feeds structure

Comment: I don't understand. What's `Feed_A`? Is it supposed to be a count (same for `Feed_B`)? If so why is it within a loop? What exactly do you want to display?

Comment: @Jeto, Feed_A and Feed_B is a type of feed
Feed_A + Feed_B together forms the Feeds.

So feed of feeds
feed.feed_type != ''" then it goes into Feed_A
feed.feed_type -= ''" then it goes into Feed_B

Comment: Then what's wrong with just testing `feed.feed_type != ''` and `feed.feed_type == ''`? (you should probably use `===` btw). If only a paragraph/title change you should follow @DavidAnthonyAcosta's advice though. No need to have two sections with 90% of the same contents.

Comment: @Jeto, I will try that, right now I am trying to get the count of Total Feeds, count of Feed_A, count of Feed_B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comments, to retrieve the count of `Feed_A` and `Feed_B`, you can make use of [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array#length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length):

```
const feedACount = feeds.filter(feed => feed.feed_type !== '').length;
const feedBCount = feeds.length - feedACount;
```

Comment: @Muirik Thanks for the edit suggestion. I accepted it, but semicolons at the end of statements are optional in both JS and TypeScript (not sure since when though, at least a little while I suppose).

Comment: It's true that they're optional. Still considered best practice to include them, however.

Comment: @Muirik Depends on who you're asking. People seem quite divided on this in general. Anyway, not the point of this question (and not relevant at all here), so let's move on :)

Comment: @Muirik, thank you I tried you code in my service :

`loadAll() {
      this.http.get(this.baseUrl).subscribe(feeds => {
        this.dataStore.feeds = feeds;

        console.log(feeds.length);

        const Reals = feeds.filter(feed => feed.feed_type !== '').length;
        console.log(Reals);

        const Fakes = feeds.length - Reals;
        console.log(Fakes);

        this._feeds.next(Object.assign({}, this.dataStore).feeds);
      }, error => console.log('Could not load feeds.'));
    }`

I want to pass this values to my component, please check my updated code,

Comment: To clarify, this was @Jeto's answer, not mine.

Comment: @Jeto, I can't pass those count from my service to component

Comment: @KamleshKatpara Yes you can, by having that code populate public properties of your component. I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish with your `Reals` and `Fakes` boolean properties though.

Comment: @Jeto, If you check my Feeds.Component.html file, I have three radio button by which I filter my feeds data, I am able to get the total no. of feeds. I just need to show the count of Reals and Fakes in View.

Comment: @Jeto i get error If I use it in service `loadAll() { this.http.get(this.baseUrl).subscribe(feeds => { this.dataStore.feeds = feeds; console.log(feeds.length); const Reals = feeds.filter(feed => feed.feed_type !== '').length; console.log(Reals); const Fakes = feeds.length - Reals; console.log(Fakes); this._feeds.next(Object.assign({}, this.dataStore).feeds); }, error => console.log('Could not load feeds.')); }`
Can you please suggest.

Comment: @Jeto

I tried your code, it gives error :

`Failed to compile. src/app/shared/services/my-service.service.ts(34,38): error TS2339: Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Object'. src/app/shared/services/my-service.service.ts(35,37): error TS2339: Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Object'.`

Comment: @KamleshKatpara What is your webservice call returning? I figured it would be an array of feeds. Anyway, there are too many things that could or could not be wrong. Try building a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) reproducing the issue and post it in your question.

Comment: @Jeto, this is what my webservice is returning => http://35.154.214.245:3000/api/feeds

Can't use my api with StackBlitz, since my api is not https

Comment: @KamleshKatpara Then it does return an array. You must not be calling `filter` on what it returns.

Comment: @Jeto, Yes it returns Object. That's why I was confused with your answer :

`const feedACount = feeds.filter(feed => feed.feed_type !== '').length;
const feedBCount = feeds.length - feedACount;`

Comment: @KamleshKatpara You can see on http://35.154.214.245:3000/api/feeds that it is an array, not an object (starts and ends with square brackets).

Comment: @Jeto Okay I see then why does this error says object:

`Failed to compile. src/app/shared/services/my-service.service.ts(34,38): error TS2339: Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Object'. src/app/shared/services/my-service.service.ts(35,37): error TS2339: Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Object'.`