# Get Count of Item from Object in Observer Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, ngfor, observers

This question is reference to my previous query: [ngFor length in Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49371837/ngfor-length-in-angular-5/)

**MyService:**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FeedsService } from './feeds.service';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators/filter';
import { Feed } from './Feed';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  feeds: Observable<Feed[]>;
  private _feeds : BehaviorSubject<Feed[]>;
  private baseUrl: string;
  Fakes: any;
  private dataStore : {
    feeds: any
  };
  Reals: number;

    // Using Angular DI we use the HTTP service
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
      this.baseUrl  = environment.API_ENDPOINT + 'feeds';
      this.dataStore = { feeds: [] };
      this._feeds = <BehaviorSubject<Feed[]>>new BehaviorSubject([]);
      this.feeds = this._feeds.asObservable();
    }
  
    loadAll() {
      this.http.get(this.baseUrl).subscribe(feeds => {
        this.dataStore.feeds = feeds;
        console.log(feeds.length);
        this.Reals = feeds.filter(feed => feed.feed_type !== '').length;
        console.log(this.Reals);
        this.Fakes = feeds.length - this.Reals;
        console.log(this.Fakes);
        this._feeds.next(Object.assign({}, this.dataStore).feeds);
      }, error => console.log('Could not load feeds.'));
    }    
      
    change(feeds) {
      this._feeds.next(feeds);
    }

}
```

Here in myService, I am able to get the total no. feeds and pass it to my component.

Now within my **feeds**, I have a field/item called feed_type so I am trying to get the count of feed_type =="" and feed_type !="".

As you can see in the above code I have named them as Reals => feed_type != ' '
and Fakes => feed_type == ' '

I am not able to pass the Reals and Fakes value to my Component and then to the View.

**Feeds Component:**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { MyService } from '../shared/services/my-service.service';
import { FeedsService } from '../shared/services/feeds.service';
import { Feeds } from '../shared/services/feeds';
import { Feed } from '../shared/services/feed';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-feeds',
  templateUrl: './feeds.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./feeds.component.scss']
})

export class FeedsComponent implements OnInit {

  feeds: Observable<Feed[]>;
  Reals: boolean;
  Fakes: boolean;
  selectedFeedType = '';
  realcount: number;


  constructor(private myService: MyService, private feedsService: FeedsService) {
    this.selectedFeedType = 'All';
    this.Reals = true;
    this.Fakes = true;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.feeds = this.myService.feeds;
    this.realcount = this.myService.Reals;
    console.log(this.myService.Reals);
    this.myService.loadAll();
  }


  SelectedFeedsType(event: any) {
    this.selectedFeedType = event.target.value;
    if (this.selectedFeedType === 'All') {
      this.Reals = true;
      this.Fakes = true;
    } else if (this.selectedFeedType === 'Reals') {
      this.Reals = true;
      this.Fakes = false;
    } else if (this.selectedFeedType === 'Fakes') {
      this.Reals = false;
      this.Fakes = true;
    }
  }

}
```

Help Appreciated, thanks.

Comment: what do you meen by "I am not able to pass the Reals and Fakes value to my Component and then to the View"? Are you getting any errors or is the data not showing the correct items?

Comment: @TjaartvanderWalt, I tried this => `this.realcount = this.myService.Reals;
    console.log(this.myService.Reals);`

Shows as undefined in component, but it in myService I can the value `this.Reals = feeds.filter(feed => feed.feed_type !== '').length;
        console.log(this.Reals);`

Comment: You are calling `console.log(this.myService.Reals)` before `this.myService.loadAll()`. `this.myService.Reals` will be undefined as you have not given it a default value when declaring the property.

Comment: @TjaartvanderWalt, tried `ngOnInit() {
    this.feeds = this.myService.feeds;
    this.myService.loadAll();
    const realcount = this.myService.Reals;
    console.log(this.myService.Reals);
  }`

Still undefined.

Comment: `loadAll()` is **asynchronous** so even if you place `this.myService.loadAll()` above your console logs in component, it will still be `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @alex commented the problem is `loadAll` method is asynchronous as it is using [`HttpClient.Get`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get)

When you call `loadAll()` it executes and continues with the next line of code in your component, it does not wait for the `HttpClient.Get` method to complete.

You need to update your service code to work with [subjects(abservable)](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html)

> A Subject is a sort of bridge or proxy that is available in some
>   implementations of ReactiveX that acts both as an observer and as an
>   Observable. Because it is an observer, it can subscribe to one or more
>   Observables, and because it is an Observable, it can pass through the
>   items it observes by reemitting them, and it can also emit new items.

- First you will have to update your `Reals` property to be of type
  Subject();
- Then you need to emit the reals value.
- You also need to subscribe to the `Reals` property so you can be
  notified when the value changes:

Service:

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs/Subject";

public Reals = new Subject<number>();

loadAll() {
      this.http.get(this.baseUrl).subscribe(feeds => {
        this.dataStore.feeds = feeds;
        console.log(feeds.length);
        this.Reals.next(feeds.filter(feed => feed.feed_type !== '').length);       
      }, error => console.log('Could not load feeds.'));
    }
```

Component:

```
...
this.myService.Reals.subscribe((reals)=>
{
    console.log(reals);
});
```

Note the **`this.Reals.next(feeds.filter(feed => feed.feed_type !== '').length);`** line.

For further reading you can search online for "Managing State in Angular Applications" for some more examples.

Comment: Getting this Error Now in Service :

`Failed to compile.

src/app/shared/services/my-service.service.ts(34,38): error TS2339: Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Object'.
src/app/shared/services/my-service.service.ts(35,37): error TS2339: Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Object'.`